# How do indicator light circuits work?

Tags: monitor, indicator

On many control panels, one finds indicator lights that indicate whether a device is working. I.e. not only whether it is switched on but whether current flows.

E.g. a car dashboard which indicates when a lamp burned out.

My question is: how do these work? Are there ready-made IC solutions? (I have a black box in front of me which has input/output for the power supply of the device monitored and smaller wires to connect to the indicator light.)

Also: another problem is that when lamps that a monitored are replaced by LED, the indicator circuit signals a fault. What is the reason for this? Is it due to the current draw being too low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sense whether current is flowing through a circuit using a very small-valued (fraction of an ohm) resistor which, in such a role, is called "current-sensing resistor". When current flows, a small voltage develops across the resistor. Not enough to produce any appreciable voltage drop in series with the device, and not enough I^2R to generate any serious heat. This small voltage can be amplified (e.g. by an op-amp) and then something can be done with that signal, like feeding it to an LED-driving comparator circuit.

Answer (score 7):

In the old days the indicator light was just placed parallel to for instance the headlights. That's what made wiring so complicated; I've been told that my previous, 1994 car had for instance more than 1.5km of wiring in it.
Nowadays everything is electronically controlled. The electronic switch which switches your headlights also measures the current and signals the board computer any defects. The board computer will switch on a light on the dashboard when the headlights are on, and another one (or blink that one) when the headlight's lamp is broken. Indicator lights may be replaced by display segments on OLED displays.

Typically the electronics in a car will communicate via CAN bus (for "Car Area Network", before it was renamed to "Controller Area Network").

Comment: Regarding cars this sounds good. What about ready-made IC solutions? Also what kind of circuits are used more generally, i.e. any usual instrumentation panel? Lights in parallel are not ideal for distriminating between fault/ok condition.

Comment: @ArikRaffaelFunke - I'm not sure what you mean by "ready-made IC solutions". In general, instrumentation panels for industrial applications will probably use a PLC with outputs controlling the indicator lamps, and inputs measuring lamp current. Can also be done with a microcontroller.

Comment: very interesting. I do really enjoy this one. I'm digging on hydrolics failsafe and monitoring systems these days. +1

Comment: @sandundhammika You might be interested in the application note I referenced in my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Linear Technology has a nice application note with a collection of current sense circuits, detailing advantages and disadvantages of various configurations.

[Linear Technology AN105](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Application%20Note/an105.pdf)

There do not appear to be ready-made ICs for driving indicator LEDs directly but it might be possible to directly use the output of a integrated current-sense IC for this purpose. E.g. the hall sensor ICs from Allegro. Example:

[Allegro ACS712](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0d88/0900766b80d885f5.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

About the LED lamps causing a fault. LEDs are much more efficient than those old filament bulbs, and draw about 15% of the current. Probably this amount of current is so low that the electronics thinks there must be a fault.

Comment: Try reverse engineering the ECU firmware and make a hex surgery where the const is stored.